# Any problems installing elementary OS Freya on an Acer Chromebook 15 CB5-571-C4T3?

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

I'd like to install elementary OS Freya on a light-weight, low-end laptop. I'm thinking of buying the Acer Chromebook 15 CBS-571-C4T3 and completely replacing Chrome OS with elementary OS Freya - specifications of the unit are as follows:

- Intel Celeron Dual-Core 3205U 1.5 GHz Processor (Broadwell)
- 2 GB DDR3L SDRAM
- 16 GB Solid-State Drive
- 15.6-Inch Screen
- Intel HD Graphics

Has anyone in this forum tried this? I'd love to hear from others who have successfully installed Freya or Luna on a Chromebook with similar specs.

What issues did you have? How did you overcome them? Please share your experience and any guidance!

Thanks.

Comment: There are some guides on the internet about installing elementary on Chromebook, you can check them out.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install elementary OS on Chromebook one of the following methods:

#### ChromeeOS - elementary OS Luna installation script for Chromebooks

ChromeeOS will install elementary OS (with ChrUbuntu) and apply automatically all the necessary fixes to run elementary OS on Chromebooks. You will be able to boot in ChromeOS or elementary OS on your Chromebook.

[GitHub link](https://github.com/Setsuna666/elementaryos-chromebook).

#### HugeGreenBug's elementary OS Freya for Haswell Chromebooks/Chromeboxes

This is ready ISO to install elementary OS Freya on Chromebooks/Chromeboxes.

[Distroshare link](https://www.distroshare.com/distros/get/42/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it specifically on a Chromebook but on some other low-end laptops.

First thing I noticed is that Freya is quite heavier on resources then Luna was. Also the graphics had quite a few glitches on Intel Core2 Duo w/ integrated graphic card and was barely usable on netbook with Intel Atom processor (and integrated graphics again).

I "solved" it by installing Xubuntu on core2duo notebook and downgrading to Luna on atom netbook which worked fine on both cases.

I reported it but the bug report has seen no attention whatsoever.

On the other hand I have quite positive experience with Acer & Linux combo. In general to someone wanting linux laptop I'd recommend Acer or Dell - I had tried both brands myself and heard from friends and both have least issues with linux. BTW the two laptops above I tried with Freya were FS and MSI. Also stay as far away from Gigabyte as possible, for your own good :D

If I were you, I'd find a store with the Chromebook you want, grabbed a USB stick with Freya and tried it there :)

Answer (score 0):

I have completed a Chromebook conversion for fun and swapped the HD.  Checkout mrchromebox.tech (Firmware Utility Script) for scripts.  You will need to install SeaBios first then the OS(Have a bootable USB made). Backup your Chrome OS firmware.  The following below is the windows version for reference(swap the windows install with Elementary OS).
 1. https://www.howtogeek.com/278953/how-to-install-windows-on-a-chromebook/
 2. http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/

Answer (score -1):

I don't think elementary OS will have any problem installing on a low-end laptop. And if there are any bugs or problems you can always report it. The problem is likely already solved.

Comment: The question was about system installation on the Chromebooks.

Comment: Which in this case is in fact a low-end laptop... so what's your point?

Comment: @quassy, installing Linux on Chromebooks is somewhat different, have to use ChrUbuntu and other tricks.