# I want install elementary OS on Chromebook any help?

Tags: chromebook

Hello guys i need install elementary OS.

Erase Chromebook system completely,and install Elementary OS on a clean installation my model is ASUS C200 I hope anyone have a guide, thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any problems installing elementary OS Freya on an Acer Chromebook 15 CB5-571-C4T3?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/783/any-problems-installing-elementary-os-freya-on-an-acer-chromebook-15-cb5-571-c4t)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Asus C200, but I just installed Elementary OS on my Acer C720p. Some of the following parts are hardware dependent. You may want to check this for your Chromebook on Google, but I hope this gives you a viable start anyway.

- Enable the developer mode in ChromeOS. Please check how you can do this.
- Open a "real" shell, i.e. press alt+ctrl+t and execute `shell` in the command line.
- Check on https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/ if your Chromebook is supported. Read through this page including the warnings and the FAQ. Decide if you really want to continue.
- run `cd;bash <(curl https://johnlewis.ie/flash_cb_fw.sh)` and first make a **backup**. Store this backup somewhere that is not your chromebook.
- Install the SeaBios payload for coreboot using the same command. It provides you several options.
- The installer may fail and tell you that your coreboot is write-protected. If that is the case please check google how to disable it. I had to remove a screw on my C720p.
- After that plugin in an Elementary OS USB install medium. On boot you need to press ESC and a boot menu will pop up. Select boot from USB.
- For me the install would not start and show me an error about not enough memory. To solve this select the installer from the Elementary OS boot menu. Press tab and add the following text line you see " mem=1024M". Press enter and the installer will start.
- Make sure that you connect your Chromebook to the internet while installing (just follow the prompt of the installer). It would not install grub correctly if it is not connected to the internet. Looks like there is a package missing on the USB drive that is required for chromebooks.
- Now your Chromebook should boot Elementary OS just fine. There is one more thing you should do: edit /etc/default/grub, remove the "mem=1024M" part found in the parameter GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX, save the file and `run sudo update-grub`  in a terminal.

That worked for me. Took some time to figure it out, but Elementary OS works fine on my Chromebook.